# Get values from 2 Tables in different Databases into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-cursor

I have a Database for say `MasterDB` which has list of Some Databases Name in a Table `tbl_B` .Each DataBase Name is identified by an ID.
The structure of the table `tbl_B` is like the following

**tbl_B**

```
ID | DB_Name
-------------
1  | DelhiDB
2  | MumbaiDB
```

There are DataBases with the same name i.e DelhiDB and MumbaiDB and each of them  have a Table with name  `tbl_C` which will have some data for eg.

**tbl_C** for Delhi

```
custIDDelhi | custNameDelhi | CustPhoneDelhi |
----------------------------------------------
     1      | John          |     123456     |
     2      | Monika        |     789945     |
```

**Please note here that the column names for Both the databases can be Different**

**Also Please note that `DelhiDB` and `MumbaiDB` are separate Database each having a table named `tbl_C`**

I want to create a Table called `tblCusotmer_Dictionary` in `MasterDB`

With Data something like this

```
ColumnName    | DataBaseName | DataBaseID | db_ColumnNamme
-----------------------------------------------------------
CustomerID    | DelhiDB      | 1          | custIDDelhi
CustomerName  | DelhiDB      | 1          | custNameDelhi
CustomerPhone | DelhiDB      | 1          | CustPhoneDElhi
CustomerID    | MumbaiDB     | 2          | custIDMumbai
CustomerName  | MumbaiDB     | 2          | custNameMumbai
CustomerPhone | MumbaiDB     | 2          | CustPhoneMumbai
```

Here I dont want any customer data just a list of column name from both the databases along with Database name and ID , 
the column `ColumnName` in the above table is the Generic Name I am giving to the column `db_ColumnNamme`

I have taken example for 2 databases and 3 columns for simplicity But there can can be N number for databases each having a table with a same name ( `tbl_c` here) with fixed no of columns.
Let me know in comments for any clarifications.

Comment: In your example, the db_columnName would have 3 rows with John and 3 with Monika?

Comment: What is your question?   How to create a table?   How to insert data?

Comment: Are this databases on same server?

Comment: Yes The Database are on the same server

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis no the 3 rows correspond to 3 columns Namely custID , custName , CustPhone

Comment: @TabAlleman  My first language isn't english .
Things may be little unclear . Ask for clarification if you are willing to help.

Comment: I believe I did ask for clarification.  Your post doesn't contain a question.   The closest thing to it is the line "I want to create a Table..."   Then at the end you talk about trying Cursors, but you don't post any code or error message.  So, what is your question?   This is an honest request for clarification.

Comment: @TabAlleman I have edited and  tried to explain in a better way .

Comment: @RajatJaiswal Please have a look at the updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood your question correctly then below is the solution which you are looking for. Let me know if it works for you.

```
  DECLARE @tblDatabaseName AS TABLE (Id INT, dbName VARCHAR(100))

--DROP TABLE #tmpREcord

INSERT INTO @tblDatabaseName(id,dbName) VALUES (1,'DelhiDB'),(1,'MumbaiDB')

DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(8000) 
DECLARE @Id INT
DECLARE @dbName AS VARCHAR(100)

CREATE TABLE #tmpRecord (
columnName VARCHAR(20),DBID INT, DatabaseName VARCHAR(100))

DECLARE cur_Traverse CURSOR FOR SELECT Id , dbName FROM @tblDatabaseName

OPEN cur_Traverse 

FETCH NEXT FROM cur_Traverse INTO @id ,@dbName 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
BEGIN
  SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO #tmpRecord (ColumnName,DbId,DatabaseName )
             SELECT  name ,' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@Id) + ' AS DBID, ''' + @dbName + ''' as dbname'
              + ' FROM ' + @dbName + '.sys.all_columns  s
                WHERE object_Id = (SELECT TOP(1) object_Id FROM ' + @dbName + '.sys.all_objects WHERE name=''tbl_C'')'


                PRINT @SQL 
  EXECUTE (@SQL)
  FETCH NEXT FROM cur_Traverse INTO @Id, @dbName
END 
CLOSE cur_Traverse
DEALLOCATE cur_Traverse

SELECT * FROM  #tmpRecord
```

Comment: I can relate to your approach Rajat but this is not exactly what i want .

Comment: I have updated the question .
Let me know if that makes sense .

Comment: I have updated the query as per your need. Please, check now.

Comment: Pleasure always.

Answer (score 0):

You appears to want :

```
select t.colsname as ColumnName, 
       b.db_name as DataBaseName,
       b.id as DataBaseID,
       t.cols as db_ColumnNamme
from tbl_C c 
cross apply (values ('custID', 'CustomerID'), ('custName', 'CustomerName'),
                    ('CustPhone', 'CustomerPhone')
            ) t (cols, colsname)
inner join tbl_B b on b.id = c.custID;
```